# How can i find a sizer in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, find, wxwidgets

I have to say my english isnt good.

Well, my problem is that i need insert a wxButton to a wxBoxSizer in a specific moment of my program. This sizer is child of other sizer and isn't a global variable. I'm in a different scope so i can't access to this wxBoxSizer.

Adding the button to the wxsizer is not a problem, i just need the wxsizer but i dont know how i get it.

I already tried functions like FindWindowById,ByName but with wxsizers but i couldn't find anything.

I hope you understand my question.If you need more information just let me know.

Comment: What *do* you have access to? The window? The parent sizer? Let's say you start from one of these; what are your criteria for identifying the child sizer? Is it guaranteed that there's only one child sizer within the parent sizer (I wouldn't rely on this - even if it's true today, it could easily change in the future)?

Comment: hi bogdan. I have access to the parent sizer and the wxbutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either locate the parent window and use its `GetSizer()` or any existing child of the sizer and then use its `GetContainingSizer()` method. There is currently no way to find the sizer itself.